# How to parse this http response in C#

Tags: c#, json

How would I parse this response using C#?

```
[  
   {  
      "date":"2016-10-01",
      "stats":[  
         {  
            "type":"subuser",
            "name":"coolguy@yahoo.com",
            "metrics":{  
               "blocks":23,
               "bounce_drops":164,
               "bounces":19,
               "clicks":0,
               "deferred":412,
               "delivered":3435,
               "invalid_emails":27,
               "opens":0,
               "processed":3481,
               "requests":3675,
               "spam_report_drops":3,
               "spam_reports":0,
               "unique_clicks":0,
               "unique_opens":0,
               "unsubscribe_drops":0,
               "unsubscribes":0
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "date":"2016-10-02",
      "stats":[  
         {  
            "type":"subuser",
            "name":"coolguy@yahoo.com",
            "metrics":{  
               "blocks":0,
               "bounce_drops":0,
               "bounces":0,
               "clicks":0,
               "deferred":95,
               "delivered":0,
               "invalid_emails":0,
               "opens":0,
               "processed":0,
               "requests":0,
               "spam_report_drops":0,
               "spam_reports":0,
               "unique_clicks":0,
               "unique_opens":0,
               "unsubscribe_drops":0,
               "unsubscribes":0
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: json.net is your friend

Comment: @pm100 i tried looking for a json.net parsing and failed :(

Comment: do you mean you cant find json.net or you dont know how to use it? It is here http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: @CarlR Tried what? Show your attempt in your question. We're not a code writing service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`JsonConvert`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) deserialize it to `dynamic` as below or create a matching class structure and deserialize it to that.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
.....

string json = File.ReadAllText("data.txt");
var deserializedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
```

Using [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) your classes should look like:

```
public class Metrics
{
    public int blocks { get; set; }
    public int bounce_drops { get; set; }
    public int bounces { get; set; }
    public int clicks { get; set; }
    public int deferred { get; set; }
    public int delivered { get; set; }
    public int invalid_emails { get; set; }
    public int opens { get; set; }
    public int processed { get; set; }
    public int requests { get; set; }
    public int spam_report_drops { get; set; }
    public int spam_reports { get; set; }
    public int unique_clicks { get; set; }
    public int unique_opens { get; set; }
    public int unsubscribe_drops { get; set; }
    public int unsubscribes { get; set; }
}

public class Stat
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Metrics metrics { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string date { get; set; }
    public List<Stat> stats { get; set; }
}
```

*These generated classes can be improved - for example not storing the `date` in a `string` but a `DateTime`*

```
string json = File.ReadAllText("data.txt");
RootObject deserializedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Comment: Ok and How would I add the variable to a textbox.text such as delivered:

Comment: @CarlR - I didn't understand what you mean

Comment: Well I am trying to get the count of the delivered counts from the response into a textbox.  Such as textbox1.text = deserializedData.delivered;  But I want to add both dates of the delivered from the response data.

Comment: Could you help me with that? Thank you by the way.

Comment: @CarlR - These are followup questions.. Take this and try to solve your followup problems.. If you decide to go with the `dynamic` version then read about using `dynamic`, if you decide to go for something like these generated classes then also read about it and use them.

Comment: @CarlR - Did this answer above help you better understand and solve the specific question?